# Bind texture to mesh in libGDX?

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx

I have a mesh generated from data in Renderables. Environment is set. Material is a simple `new Material()`.

```
            ... /*init renderable*/

    /*set mesh parameters*/
    renderable.mesh = new Mesh(false, 
            (int)(meshVertexArray.length/SurfaceBuilder.__ELEMENTSPERVERTEX__), /*!vertices, not cordinates*/ 
            meshIndexArray.length,
            new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position,3,"a_position"),
            new VertexAttribute(Usage.Normal,3,"a_normal"),
            new VertexAttribute(Usage.TextureCoordinates,2,"a_texCoords"),
            new VertexAttribute(Usage.ColorPacked,4, "a_color")
    );

            ... /*set vertices*/
```

The mesh is generated properly, but I can't see the textures, only the gray (shaded) triangles. I did try the rtfm method, but so far I saw no way to bind a texture, so it displays properly in libGDX, only with shaders, and I'm not using them (I'm catching up on them after this feature is implemented). Is there a way in libGDX to bind textures to a mesh without shaders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your texturing code, maybe try specify a texture for your material using the following format:

```
    Material mat = new Material();
    //set the diffuse channel on the texture using some texture
    mat.set(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(new Texture("crate.jpg")));
```